# Analog multiplexing in telephony

Tags: discussion, support

I have been told to come here to dispute questions that are put on hold.

I asked a question earlier today about [PBX CO connections and if there were standards that were basically the analog equivalent of PRI](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42193/pbx-co-trunks-analog-multiplexing-analog-version-of-pri). As expected, the question was put on hold,

Is there a better forum to ask this question on? Several other of my PBX questions on Network Engineering were not closed or put on hold, so I don't understand why this one would have been different, particularly since this question was about interface standards rather than about specific products and it was not opinionated.

I am trying to find out what the telco. equivalent/version/name/offering is of an analog variant of PRI - basically analog multiplexing. Cost and local telco. offerings aside, I'm trying to find out what this would be called and how I could get it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ron Maupin tried to explain to you more than once in the comments why the question was closed. I don't see what I can add to that.

I have no idea what SE would be more appropriate, but that (or the fact that other PBX related questions were not closed) does not make *this* question on topic. What you're asking is off topic for this SE.

As it is, I can't see how we could help you more than Ron did, even though the question *is* off topic. As he pointed out, the local delivery done is not something you can chose from your telco, they decide how that's done.

Comment: But is there a name for what it would be called? Why can't anyone tell me that??

Comment: because it is *off topic*. Most people here don't do analog telephony.

Comment: This was mentioned in the comments, but to reiterate: IT DOESN'T EXIST.  The **digital** T-carrier system literally dates back to the 1950's and (with the equivalent E and J series systems) has been more-or-less the dominant method of multiplexing worldwide ever since.  You're literally going to have as much luck asking for a telegraph hookup as an analog mux to a CO.  If you want analog connectivity buy a bunch of POTS lines, but (as mentioned in your original question) literally the first hop after each of those analog lines is an AD converter.